# How to assign IP when a machine is connected to the same network via two interfaces?

Tags: networking, internet, ip

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 machine connected to the same subnet via two different interfaces, `wlan0` and `eth0`. The machine is used for normal  browsing of internet only. I am to manually assign IP addresses to both the network connections.

Is it okey to assign the same IP to both the network connections even though both the interfaces are physically connected? I can save my precious IPv4 addressed and avoid assigning two IPs to a single machine.

Or should we give different IPs to both the interfaces to avoid IP conflicts?

If the answer is a "No". Please also tell me why it is so. What I can't seem to understand is that the layer in which google chrome (for example)
runs won't mind how it got the data (ip layer), as long as it got the data.

Comment: Different IPs. You don't want the two interfaces alternating as the owner of the IP. You can bridge the two, and then assign a single IP to the bridge. Though I don't see the point, why not just disable one?

Comment: @muru Oh, I always thought that only one connection is active at a time. I should be wrong about that. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The metric determines the priority but both are in an active state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it okay to assign the same IP to both the network connections...

No. this would not be okay<s>, by any means</s>.  This would most likely cause problems.

> ...assuming that only one of the connections will be used at a time

Well, if it's truly only using one at a time (meaning that only one of the interfaces is up at a time), then you shouldn't see any issue.  This would be similar to a machine falling off the WiFi, and then your router re-assigning that same IP to a new machine;  it happens all the time.

- You can list your NICs with: `ifconfig`
- You can turn off an interface: `ifdown eth0`
- You can turn on an interface: `ifup eth0`

So, I guess the answer lies in how precious your IPv4 addresses on your LAN really are, to do something not recommended, as well as how you use your computer day-to-day.

---

Having two NICs on the same IP is technically possibly, but is not trivial to set up.  You could use bonding or LACP to do one of two things:

1. Increase the available bandwidth ([bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_bonding))
2. Have a default interface that can fall back to another interface if  the primary goes down (failover)

---

#### Assuming you use a typical setup (different IPs/dhcp)

Different applications may act differently depending upon your IP switching.  It is very-client specific, but browsers, such as `chromium-browser`, should see very little issue if you change your IP (as long as you don't load a page while you switch IPs/NICs).  Browsers typically make and close connections quickly, which makes them resilient to these changes.

Some clients, such as `ssd` may see hickups or disconnects, but behind a NAT router you'll probably not see many issues.  Changing your IP/NIC on an application that streams or keeps a constant connection is more likely to cause an issue.

---

#### Assuming you use a single NIC at a time, with the same IP

Be aware that some hardware will learn paths to different machines (routes) and need time or to be reset if a route to an IP changes (ie: You use the same IP on two different NICs).  This could cause additional issues you wouldn't see if you just had a normal, dhcp setup on the two NICs.

---

#### How do you use your computer?

Do you stay under one LAN, or do you travel with your machine?  If you stay under one LAN, you might be able to get the same IP working on both NICs, but these settings may cause issues when you travel.

---

#### IPv4 Shortage

Routers nowadays seem to be using 192.168.1.0/24 (255.255.255.000) subnet.  That gives you 256 addresses.  This is typically enough for a home environment.

If you have 256+ machines, then you have the option of creating and the fun of routing between multiple subnets.  You could go with 192.168.2.0/24 and that'd give you 256 additional addresses.  Or you could go with 192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.000.000) which would give you a whopping 65,536 addresses.

It is true that the world is running low on IPv4 addresses, but there are a few [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) reserved that should suite your needs.

Comment: In OP's case, the second quote is qualified by "both the interfaces are physically connected", so the situation isn't as nice.

Comment: @muru, are you suggesting that the OP couldn't do, or would find issues with something such as `ifdown eth0 ;  ifup wlan0`? (ie: only one interface is up at a time)?

Comment: On the contrary. I've suggested doing exactly that to the OP.

Comment: @muru I've updated the question. [See the changes](https://askubuntu.com/posts/778251/revisions).